# Map a vagrant disk to ansible host file

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to create partitions in Vagrant vm and to map them to an ansible host file but the play that i'm running is not recognizing them.

Here's the Vagrantfile configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
    libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => '/dev/vdb', :bus => 'scsi'
    libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => '/dev/vdc', :bus => 'scsi'
    libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => '/dev/vdd', :bus => 'scsi'
    libvirt.storage :file, :size => '20G', :device => '/dev/vdf', :bus => 'scsi'
  end
  config.vm.box = "roboxes/centos9s"
  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    SHELL
  end
```

and the host file where i have configured the disk:

```
disk:
  - name: swap
    device: /dev/vdb
    partnr: 1
    label: gpt
    fstype: linux-swap
    mkfs: swap
  - name: var
    device: /dev/vdc
    partnr: 1
    label: gpt
    fstype: ext4
    mkfs: ext4
    fsopt: -m0
  - name: opt
    device: /dev/vdd
    partnr: 1
    label: gpt
    fstype: ext4
    mkfs: ext4
    fsopt: -m0
```